# boot ubuntu server from live media to repair previous install

Tags: boot, server, filesystem, live-usb, fsck

I'm trying to boot ubuntu server from live media.  I'm trying to repair my current ubuntu server I'm using my original install thumb drive.  I'm working on asus hardware.  When I try to launch from the thumb drive on uefi partition I only get choices to:

```
install ubuntu
oem install
check disk issues
boot and install hwe
```

or if I change the boot order to prioritize the thumb drive it goes to a gui boot screen I get the options:

```
install ubuntu
oem install
check disk issues
test memory
boot and install hwe
```

then I can't get a terminal screen to launch, I've tried ctl+alt+T

if I hit F1 it says I should be able to run ubuntu off live media in terminal, but doesn't tell you how to get to terminal.

My end goal I'd like to run fsk -y on the drive I have my existing install on so I can try to repair any files that were damaged by a recent power outage.

any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Desktop installation ISO can be booted in "Try Ubuntu" mode, you will have a GUI *and* be able to launch a Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reach a live shell in the Ubuntu Server image,

- First, select `install ubuntu` (you are not yet committing to an install).
- Then, look for the "Help" menu in the upper right corner.
- The option to open a Live shell environment is in that Help menu.

or

- First, select `install ubuntu` (you are not yet committing to an install).
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or F3 or F4 or F5 or F6) to reach a shell.

Comment: thank you!  that worked, and this has been driving me nuts